# Fireworks in gravity field

Tags: classical-mechanics

Suppose we have a central (with center at the point $G$) gravity field in the plane (the force acting on each particle is equal to $k/r^2$ (Newton's law), where $k$ is some constant and $r$ is a distance to the origin). Suppose infinitely many particles (fireworks) start to move from the same point $O$ (different from the origin) with the same speed in arbitrary directions. It is known that trajectory of each particle is an ellipse with focus at the origin (Kepler's law) and envelope of all trajectories is also an ellipse. Is it true that the locus of particles at each moment is a circle?

[image]

Comment: You tag this as classical physics but the wave properties of particles is precisely what quantum theory describes and the study of the hydrogen atom in quantum theory is well described everywhere.  I'm not sure what you mean by "wavefront" in a classical context.

Comment: By "wavefront" I mean a locus of all the particles at the same moment. For example, in the case of earth's gravity trajectories of all the particles are parabolas, envelope of trajectories is a parabola and all wavefronts are circles.

Comment: What do you mean by "the locus of particles"? When you say "Is it true", are you referring to a statement elsewhere? If yes, you should give a link or reference to the source. If it is a calculation/conclusion you have made yourself, you should explain your reasoning here.

Comment: By "the locus of particles" I mean "geometrical locus". At moment $t=0$ all particles coincide with the point $O$. At moment $t>0$ all particles (points) form some curve $\gamma_t$. I'm wondering what can be said about $\gamma_t$. Is it true, that it is always a circle? I don't know the answer. But maybe it is known.

Comment: Is this a 2-dimensional or 3-dimensional question? If the latter, wouldn't they lie on a sphere? Have you calculated the trajectory for enough points to see if your "circle" hypothesis is plausible?   Your question should probably include something like "If gravity did not exist, the particles would simply expand as a circular/spherical shell. Will this shell distort when there is a gravitational force from G." You probably also need to specify that you are interested in the limit where the gravitational self-attraction of the particles is negligible.